# AutoComplete JQuery com Seleção em Sequência

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocompletar, ashx

Tenho um campo texto no banco sql server varchar(MAX).

Estou usando JQuery e C# para fazer um autocomplete.

Este é preenchido através de um arquivo "autocomplete.ashx" chamado pelo jqyery.

Meu campo no banco de dados é formado por uma string que é montada dinamicamente em níveis que são divididos pelo caracter especial "\".

Exemplo de string (campo nomeCompleto): 
"primeiro nível \ segundo \ terceiro \ quarto \ quinto"

A tabela é composta basicamente pelos seguintes campos:
Id, NomeCompleto, Nivel

Diante desde cenário o que eu preciso é que o autocomplete funcione da seguinte forma:

Quando clicado sem digitar nada aparecem apenas os registros do primeiro nível, quando for feita a seleção do primeiro nível automaticamente o autocomplete aparece com as opções de segundo nível dentro do primeiro nível, quando selecionado o segundo nível apareçam os registros do terceiro nível e assim sucessivamente.

Atualmente está funcionando como um autocomplete normal, pegando qualquer parte da string completa.

```
public class ContaAutoComplete : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var nomeCompleto = context.Request.QueryString["term"];

        var contas = Conta.ObterVarios(idCliente: MySession.Cliente.Id, nomeCompleto: nomeCompleto)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                value = x.NomeCompleto,
                label = x.NomeCompleto
            });


        using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(context.Response.Output))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, contas);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $("#<%=txtContaAutoComplete.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
                source: 'ContaAutoComplete.ashx',
                minLength: 0
            }).focus(function () {

                $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
            });
        });

    </script>
```